# NameError: name 'number' is not defined

Tags: python

I have a code like below

```
a=25
b=20
#number=0
if a < b == True:
    number = 1
elif a >b == True:
    number = 2
print(number)
```

When i execute this i get the following error

```
NameError: name 'number' is not defined
```

When i initialize the `number = 0` like below

```
a=25
b=20
number=0
if a < b == True:
    number = 1
elif a >b == True:
    number = 2
print(number)
```

then i am not getting the output as `2`, i am getting `0` instead, what am i missing here

Comment: Just use `if a < b:`.  There's no need to explicitly compare that result to `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put a parenthesis around the condition.

**Ex:**

```
a=25
b=20
#number=0
if (a < b) == True:
    number = 1
elif (a > b) == True:
    number = 2
print(number)
```

or:

```
if a < b:
    number = 1
elif a > b:
    number = 2
print(number)
```

- You are currently doing `(a < b) and (b == True)` & `(a > b) and (b == 20)`

Comment: This answer is correct but for safety you should either add a condition to assign number when a == b or set a default value for number above the if statements.

Comment: @superbeck. You are right.

Comment: Nice answer. Will you give explanation about parenthesis of your first code please?

Comment: Without the parenthesis the if statement is evaluating (a < (b == True)) because of the order python evaluations operations in expressions. Adding the parenthesis where @Rakesh put them specifies that you want to compare a and b, then compare the result of that comparison to 'True'. (edited for clarity)

Comment: This solves the problem but the `== True` is still unnecessary, and if you remove the `== True` the parentheses are also unnecessary.

Comment: Without the parenthesis, (b == True) evaluates to True since b is non-zero. After that a < True and a > True force the conversion of a to boolean (a is True since it is non-zero) and neither True<True or True>True evaluates to True so neither path of the if/elif tree is taken. If you assign number=0 before the if statement, 0 gets printed, if you don't assign number to anything before the if statement then it is undefined when the print statement tries to evaluate it.